# What do I put in my .NET/C# MouseOver method to show a tooltip over a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, tooltip, picturebox

Good afternoon,

I am new to object-oriented programming, .NET and C#. I am studying these previous mentioned topics and presently am doing a relatively simple programming assignment which turned out not to be so simple after all, at least ... for me still.

I want to create a Windows Form Application which contains one form that is filled with country flags (.png, 128px x 128px). In the Form_OnLoad() the files are read and the flags are stored array of PictureBox objects and set several object attributes. Then the form is filled neatly in rows of 8 flags. So far so good.

### Problem:

I would like to add a MouseOver event-handler attached to each PictureBox that generates a ToolTip with the country name of the specific flags. In the event-handler I don't know what code to put after what I have managed to do myself already. Specifically, I would like to address the array with flags from the MouseOver event-handler method, but it's not visible from there. I am just stuck here, although my intuition tells me that I am not far from my goal, at this moment my mind decided to give up on me a few meters away from the finish line. Would someone be so kind to help me out with this please?

Here's what I got already:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WorldFlags 
{
    public partial class FormWorldFlags :Form {

        public FormWorldFlags() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int col = 0, row = 0;
            string imageDirectory = @"D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ITvitae\WorldFlags\flags\";
            string[] imageFileList = Directory.GetFiles(imageDirectory);
            PictureBox[] countryFlag = new PictureBox[imageFileList.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < imageFileList.Length; i++) {
                countryFlag[i] = new PictureBox();
                countryFlag[i].Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFileList[i]);
                countryFlag[i].Image = Image.FromFile(imageFileList[i]);
                countryFlag[i].Location = new Point(col * 128 + 1, row * 128 + 1);
                countryFlag[i].Size = new Size(128, 128);
                countryFlag[i].MouseHover += FormWorldFlags_MouseHover;
                if (col + 1 == 8) {
                    row++;
                    col = 0;
                } else
                    col++;
                Controls.Add(countryFlag[i]);
            }
        }

        private void FormWorldFlags_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ToolTip countryName = new ToolTip();
            countryName.SetToolTip(?????)
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Joeri van der Heijden

Comment: It is not obvious where you are going to get a name from when all you got is a list of files.  Consider `((PictureBox)sender).Name`

Comment: Thanks Hans. That's it! Awesome!

Comment: countryName.SetToolTip((PictureBox)sender, ((PictureBox)sender).Name);

Answer (score -1):

change your handler to the following:

```
private void FormWorldFlags_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ToolTip countryName = new ToolTip();
    countryName.SetToolTip(sender, "country name");
}
```

If you want to access the array within the handler you can can just move it out of the form load function. Alternatively you can make use of the Tag property when loading the images and access the value in the handler.